# 2 drum stools broken in 2 years, both the same way at the stem, is that normal?

Tags: drums, equipment

2 drum stools broken in 2 years, both the same way at the stem near the 2nd hole, is that normal?

Before snapping 2 of them, I played drums for nearly 10 years with the same drumset and same stool without a single problem.

Help? Recommendation? Am I doomed? Is stuff made nowadays not even worth purchasing anymore?

[image]

Comment: If that's the exact model you are using then I can't help but notice the **holes** drilled into the stem. Don't buy that model, it is cheap and I hear the stems break easily. Buy a nice throne that will last and doesn't have holes drilled into the part that has to not break.

Comment: Have you put on weight?

Comment: Are they both the same model of stool?

Comment: First thing I do with that sort of stool is ram a round section of wood into the top tube, and drill through the one hole to be used. Another idea is to put bolts and nuts into empty holes. No hole = no stress point.Obviously not ideal if the stool keeps getting taken apart for gigs - but I wouldn't use that sort for them anyway.

Comment: Have you started to use a double bass drum pedal, playing with heels up?

Comment: Yes, they were the same model.  Also, I do not take my drum apart, as I only drum at home.  I have not "started" using a double bass drum, been using it for more than a decade now.  I'm an adult and I have not gained any weight at all.  Only changed the head once, so it's not like that I usually break my instrument, but these 2 stools didn't last even remotely close to what I expected.  I like the idea of bolting a rod of wood inside the metal tube to help it stress less, good idea.

Comment: @Tim : Please could you make your reply into an answer, I'll accept it, because I literallly just REPAIRED the broken stool by inserting a recycled hard wood floor piece TIGHTLY fitted inside the metal tube and while I was at it, I drilled a hole 2 inches lower, which made an appreciable difference while playing and I tested it by playing 3 tunes, namely Dream Theater - Deja Vu (twice) and Rise Against - Drones, all of this in under 45 minutes.  I'm shocked as the stool even works better than the day I purchased it.  WOW :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I do with that sort of stool is ram a round section of wood into the top tube, and drill through the one hole to be used. Another idea is to put bolts and nuts into empty holes. No holes = no stress points. Obviously not ideal if the stool gets taken apart for gigs - but I wouldn't use that sort for them anyway.

Comment: @that-ben, while you're at it, be sure to check that the top socket/flange  on the seat is a blind one and not simply capped by the plywood under the seat. Drummers have suffered horrific injuries when the post has pierced the plywood seat base and continued on.

Comment: @AreelXocha , we cannot really see it that well in the picture I posted in the question, but the post flange is actually the hardest piece of metal in the whole seat, but the flange is NOT blind, so you've got me anxious now.  Tough, that flange and the post are contacting metal to metal, not metal to plywood.  They basically used a socket weld flange, so there's a small inner lip of metal inside and the seat post pushes on that small lip.  Thank you so much for your care in replying with this additional detail. I cant +1 (no rep) but I'll be back to +1 you. See: https://tinyurl.com/y9b4fdc7

Comment: @AreelXocha - simple solution to a potential pain in the backside: drill through the flange and post, one side will suffice, and pop rivet or self tapper into both. Means the seat is fixed, won't swivel or come off, but won't become proctalgic...

Comment: @Tim But isn't what the seat already does with its butterfly screw that you screw in to tighten the seat when you assemble it? (I mean the top butterfly screw, there are 2, one on the stem and one on the top end flange)

Comment: Possibly - can't tell from picture. Some have no screws, so can rotate, and if they have a hollow boss at the top, that could allow the tube to penetrate the wood of the seat, I guess. I don't/won't use those, for obvious reasons...

Answer (score 0):

Buy a solid stool. The econo model is fine for a lot of situations, but you're obviously having trouble finding one that suits your needs. I'd recommend a stool with a solid threaded upright. They're expensive but can often be found used for under $100. Good luck.